# Risk-like game on unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Well, I'm new to unity and I'm trying to make a risk-like game, but 
I'm struggling in the first steps.

Want I want to do is make dots, that are going to be the conquistable locations, and jointing them with lines to show to the player wich locations are connected together. My problem is: How can I make this lines, that the player must see? How can I position this line using the locations position?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a line using two Vector3 points in unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19236482/1092820)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use LineRenderer for the same.
Have to give positions list of Vector3 & can create the line.

Comment: But the player could see it ?

Comment: @Tyks please simply for google [`Unity LineRenderer Manual`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html). And yes ofcourse the player could see it .. that's the whole purpose of it ;)